# How to implement the creation of Background-tasks or services for a specific user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, background-service

In my ASP.Net Core with MVC (Razorpages) I want to be able to let users click on a 'START' button which in the backend should start a (potentially long-running) background task or service.

It should occasionally send updates to the UI for that user. Probably through some JS/AJAX request.
The user, while being on that page, should receive those updates and see them on-screen.
It is important that updates **are not shared** across all users (hence wanting to create the background-service for a specific user).
Also when the user navigates to a different page and navigates back, it should still keep updating from the same background-service/thread.

**My own 2 cents**
My first instinct is that I should keep track of the user's ID within the background-task, so I can retrieve the background-service that belongs to a specific user and receive updates when the user is on the correct page.

However, the way I have implemented this seems like a big code smell and I do not fully understand how to actually update the user's UI with it... I seem to be stuck.

**My question**
I was wondering if others may have ideas on how to successfully implement the creation of Background-tasks or services for a specific user? Or that maybe I am missing something obvious I haven't thought of myself. Anybody any ideas?

Thanks!

What I tried was the following.

I created a background service:

```
    public class SomeService : IHostedService
    {
        private Guid _userId;

        public EventHandler UpdateUiEvent;

        public void SetUserId(Guid userId)
        {
            _userId = userId;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Do stuff on a loop
                UpdateUI();
                await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void UpdateUI()
        {
            EventArgs eventArgs = new EventArgs();
            UpdateUiEvent?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
```

Secondly I have a controller with an action which starts the service when a user calls the method 'StartServiceForUser' from the Razor-page (AJAX):

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<SomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public SomeController(ILogger<SomeController> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called from AJAX-request in Razor-page UI.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StartServiceForUser(Guid userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SomeService>();
            if (service == null) throw new Exception("Service is null.");

            service.SetUserId(userId);
            service.UpdateUiEvent += OnUiUpdated;

            await service.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        return Ok("Service has started");
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the UpdateUI event is fired in the 'SomeService' class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnUiUpdated(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // How will I push this update to the user?
    }
}
```

As seen in the comment of the OnUiUpdated method, I do not understand how to proceed further...
How will I push this update to the user?
I have the feeling I am doing something completely wrong and do not know how else to get my head around this problem. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit 1** somebody suggested in the comments I should take a look at SignalR for client-server communication. This helps, however does not yet solve the problem of having a long-running (or continuous-running) operation and updating the UI regularly.

Comment: If it can help you, for server-to-client data escalation, I suggest using SignalR rather than doing your own method. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio. This is useful for performing server-side processing but informing the client of this through a progress bar, for example.

Comment: @Kalves thanks for your response and input. I did not know about SignalR and it looks like it covers my idea of being able to send/receive messages that go through the backend and to a specific user. 

It does not however completely solve my problem yet as to how to process a long-running backend operation and keep updating the client regularly. Is it possible with SignalR and how would one go about and implement this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that with SignalR. As to how: [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0#hubs). Try some tutorials and make a proof of concept. If you get stuck, make a new question where you show what you tried and clearly explain which part of the implementation you're stuck on.

Comment: @RomenKlaassen you can't send notifications to clients from a Background service alone. You need to use a client notification technology like WebSickets, push notifications, server side events or long polling. SignalR abstracts that allowing you to send a notification to one client, a group of clients or everyone without having to deal with the underlying protocols, retrying, recovering connections etc. Once you create a SingalR hub you *can* send notifications to it from a background service

Comment: using signal can help you, and if you consider a high volumn signalr usage, you can also take [using Azure Signalr Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core) into consideration.

Comment: These are all great suggestions! Thanks a lot. I have looked at SignalR and I seem to understand the gist of things…. I will try to test some things out myself and come back with a question if Im stuck again.